Omnicomplete not working in Vimtex
I am long time user of overleaf and I wanted to try vimtex. I am using ubuntu with WSL. It all works except I cannot use omnicomplete. I have some files that have labels, and a bibliography.
Now here is the problem. Omnicomplete doesn't work in the subject files. Only in the main.tex file. the citations themselves do work if I type them manually, but I'd like to use omnicomplete so I do not have to remember all of them. Is there a way to make use of omnnicomplete in the different subfiles?
Here is a more detailed view of the problem:
My tree looks like this:
└── VIM
    ├── Main
    │   ├── bibliography.bib
    │   ├── main.aux
    │   ├── main.bbl
    │   ├── main.blg
    │   ├── main.fdb_latexmk
    │   ├── main.fls
    │   ├── main.log
    │   ├── main.pdf
    │   ├── main.synctex.gz
    │   ├── main.tex
    │   └── main.toc
    └── Subjects
        ├── Subject1
        │   ├── subjecta.tex
        │   └── subjectb.tex
        └── Subject2
            └── subjectc.tex. 

my main.tex file looks like this:
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}

\begin{document}
\section*{Subjects}

\input{../Subjects/Subject1/subjecta.tex}
\input{../Subjects/Subject1/subjectb.tex}
\input{../Subjects/Subject2/subjectc.tex}

\cite{test}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}                                   

And my subject files look like this (but then changed to other letters appropriately to their name):
\section{a}\label{a}
This is section a

with a .bib file that looks like this:
@book{test,
  author    = {Leslie Lamport},
  title     = {LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
  edition   = {2nd},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year      = {1994},
  address   = {Boston}
}


and lastly my ~/.vimrc file looks like this:
set number
cd ~/VIM/ 
filetype plugin on
colorscheme delek
syntax on

call plug#begin()
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
call plug#end()

"Vimtex Setup
syntax enable
let g:vimtex_view_method = 'zathura'
let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'latexmk'

"Vimtex settings
let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
set conceallevel =1
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'
highlight Conceal ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
let g:vimtex_view_general_options = '--synctex-forward @line:@col:@tex @pdf'

"omnifunction
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete



And how, exactly, do you use "omnicomplete"?

By omnicomplete do you mean using vanilla Vim or do you mean using some kind of Vim plugin?

@romainl With omnicomplete I mean using  and . In the main text, in I type \ref{ and than press those buttons a list appears of all the labels. Same goes for \cite{. In the other text file I can also type it manually, and  and  after \ref{ and \cite{ give the error: Pattern not found, and I do not know how get this to work

@VivianDeSmedt No, I am just using vanilla vim, no plugins other than vimtex.

What is the output of :verbose set omnifunc? when in a tex buffer?

@romainl  omnifunc=vimtex#complete#omnifunc
Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/complete.vim line 20

This means that the plugin is responsible for providing completion and thus that you should use its issue tracker.

@KarlYngveLervåg could be a question for you :-)
